# Django is not recognizing my custom user's user type to enter a protected page view (RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no usertype)

Tags: python, django, authentication, user-input

I am having issues with Django defining a custom user, which in this case is "cust" (short for customer) in Django 2.1. I have several other user types which contain separate registration forms to register them as a specific user type. I have built this from the tutorial *"How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django"* by Vitor Freitas, which eliminates Django's default user management system. My goal is to have a protected view (customer hub) which only customers can enter, and so on for other user types.

Below is the error and code which comprises my project:

---

### Traceback

**RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /companyusers/cust/**

**User has no cust.**

```
File "/home/companysite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  189.         self.object = self.get_object()

File "/home/companysite/companysite/companyusers/views/cust.py" in get_object
  38.         return self.request.user.cust

File "/home/companysite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  214.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

File "/home/companysite/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  414.                     self.related.get_accessor_name()

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /companyusers/cust/
Exception Value: User has no cust.
```

### models.py

This file is where I classify each of the custom user types (i.e, I have 2 other classes and Booleans which are written identically).

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_cust = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Cust(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cust', primary_key=True)
```

### cust.views.py

This is the views file for the customer, which includes the form and hub view. I am not sure if I am writing the hub view correctly to verify the user is a customer.

```
class CustSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = CustSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'cust'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('cust:custhub')

@method_decorator([login_required, cust_required], name='dispatch')
class CustHubView(UpdateView):
    model = Cust
    template_name = 'companyusers/cust/custhub.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cust:custhub')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.cust
```

### forms.py

This is the forms file where I am registering the user as a customer, to which I am not sure if the user type Boolean is being changed.

```
class CustSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_cust = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

### cust.urls.py

This is the url which I am invoking the customer hub view onto.

```
path('cust/', include(([
    path('', cust.CustHubView.as_view(), name='custhub'),
], 'companyusers'), namespace='cust')),
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a step where you actually create the Cust object for a User.

Comment: I see, would that be corrected by making changes to the models.py file?

Comment: You could do it with a signal, or alternatively in the form save method.

Comment: If I were to use the form save method, would I make my changes in the def get_context_data and def form_valid already established?